# DC Battery Stability

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, dc, 12v

I have a 12 V load that works by connecting an adapter from the AC socket and this adapter output 12v to the load. I decided to make a 12 v battery that can charged and the feed this load , all the work is done perfectly but the problem is that the battery when connected to the load its output voltage varies from 12 til 0 and the increase and continues like that, which may damage my load, so i think i should use a voltage regulator that outputs 12 v but it will work? if yes what kind of regulators i can buy?? 
Note : the load takes 1.2 A and the batteries are 4000 mAh

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, could you add a schematic? But: if I'm understanding it right, it sounds like you want a 12V-to-12V step-up/step-down regulator with at least 1.2A output current?

Comment: If your battery voltage is going all the way to zero, though, you have some bigger problems than just regulating the output.

Comment: Yes my point of view is as you understood, and the problem  here is that the voltage is going dwown to zero for 1-2 seconds and then rise up to take it desired value, how can i solve such problem??

Comment: you're going to have to give more details on the load. The battery voltage going to zero indicates that your battery is being periodically short-circuited which is not a good thing.

Comment: The load is a university project that needs 12 v and it worked properly when i fed it with an adapter (12v, 3A), this load consists of many circuits that used as a students manual for using amplifier...but if there is a short-circuit, why is the load working properly with the adapter, and if the short-circuit is from the battery, why the indications are true when testing the battery without load and the voltage is stable 12v??

Comment: Can you give a schematic of your load and how you're connecting the battery to it?

Comment: i will tomorrow, but can you answer me my last comment question please?

Comment: I can't without more information.

Comment: okay, i will post the schematic tomorrow ..

Comment: @Felthry the OP is getting the 12V from and adapter and not from a battery.   The question is how to use a 12V battery with a charger rather than an adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a 8.4V LiPo battery pack rather than 12.6V.
An 8.4 will would use a  DC-DC step-up boost converter.
A 12.8V would require a combination step-up/step-down converter.
Off the shelf solutions are few for a 1.2 A, 12V - 12V chargers and regulators.

But you already have a 12V battery pack.

You could use the versatile [Linear Tech LT3652 Battery Charger](http://www.linear.com/docs/28522)

Input voltages from 5V to 32V 
Will charge up to 2A
Works with Lead Acid, Li-ion, LiPo, and Li-phosphate.

---

**Example 8.4V Li-ion charger powered with 12V AC adapter:**

[image]

---

**Example 12V Lead Acid charger powered with 5 VDC to 32 VDC :**

[image]

---

---

Then for the output regulation the Linear Tech [LTC 3111 12V 1.5A Buck-Boost DC/DC Converter](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3111fa.pdf)
With low battery shut off.

[image]

---

If you want to switch between the AC adapter and battery without the voltage dropping to zero you can use a Linear Tech [LTC4358 Ideal Diode Switch](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4358fa.pdf)  .

[image]

---

Or a Linear Tech [LTC4412 Automatic Switch](http://www.linear.com/docs/1527)

[image]